# Use static C++ library in Eclipse for Java

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, java-native-interface, static-libraries

I would like to use an existing static C++ library in my Java program. I read [that it should be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493337/linking-static-library-with-jni). And the steps would be (nearly) the same [as for linking dynamic libraries](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/178). Unfortunately if I try to load the library with:

```
static { 
    System.loadLibrary("mylibrary");    
}
```

I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mylibrary in java.library.path
```

I tried setting the java.library.path before the `System.loadLibrary` call manually, but it does not help:

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "/workspace/LibraryTest/lib/");
```

Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in run configurations for the project does also not fix the problem. I get the same error.  For shared libraries it works fine though. Currently I'm using Oracle Java8 in Eclipse Mars on Debian Jessie. Does the library need to hava a `JNI_OnLoad_mylibrary` method? Anyone experienced similar problems?

**EDIT**

tried /usr/lib directory and added `JNI_OnLoad_mylibrary`. No success.

Comment: This has been answered before, rather well, here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493337/linking-static-library-with-jni

Comment: That was the post i already linked in my question. I know it has to be possible, but it is not working. Maybe i missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your code isn't relocatable? That seems like it might upset the JVM. Recompile with `-fPIC` and see what happens.

From the answer to the other question, you need `JNI_OnLoad_name-of-your-library` to be defined in the binary for this to work. Did C++ name mangling ruin your day? You'll probably need to `extern "C"` that function for it to be findable to the JVM.

Comment: I updated the library and added the extern keyword for the JNI_OnLoad_mylibrary (an UnLoad) method. Also compiled the library with -fPIC. No errors during compile time. The library runs fine if I call it from C++. But  Eclipse is still telling me "no mylibrary in java.library.path". Just to be sure, it is sufficient to name the method JNI_OnLoad_mylibrary if the static library file name is libmylibrary.a?

Comment: I can answer the question in my last comment: yes, it is sufficient to name the method JNI_OnLoad_mylibrary. At least that is, what the JNI documentations says. However the main problem, that the static library is not found remains. Any ideas or hints are highly appreciated.

Comment: You could compile the static library into a shared library and use that:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655163/convert-a-static-library-to-a-shared-library

Other than that, I'm prettymuch out of ideas. What you're doing _should work_.
Maybe you compiled the library for the wrong arch? Wrong bitness? Used processor extensions you don't have?

Comment: Currently I'm making a shared library from the static one. Sadly I don't have the time to check all the possible problems... Guess I will have look into this in more detail in the future. If I find a solution I will post it here.

Comment: Sorry I can't be more help. The JNI is very fussy about a whole bunch of different things, and it doesn't often give good errors when things go wrong. You often end up stuck with "Check _all_ the things!"