# Java native interface and registering native methods

Tags: java, java-native-interface

What is the difference between system.loadlirary () and registernative () in jni? Can registernative() method can be used to use .exe or .cpp without creating .dll? Is there any way to to achieve something like this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linking static library with JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493337/linking-static-library-with-jni)